# How to choose were Image Intervention should store the images?

Tags: laravel, intervention

Im trying to save a resized copy of an image that has been uploaded, but Image Interventions doesent seem to know in what root directory to begin in, or maybe it is just me that dosent know how to configure it propertly.

This is my code in `AvatarImageController@store`

```
public function store(Request $request, Game $game)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('game_image')) {
        $request->validate([
            'game_image' => 'mimes:jpeg,png|max:1014'
        ]);

        $file = $request->file('game_image');
        $filename_thumbnail = "thumb_". $file->hashName();
        $path_full = $request->file('game_image')->store('images/test_folder');
        $path_thumb = $request->file('game_image')->storeAs('images/test_folder/thumbs', $filename_thumbnail);

        // resize image
        $path_thumb = Intervention::make("./storage/app/public/" . $path_thumb)->resize(300, 200);
        $path_thumb->save();

        $image = new Image;
        $image->full = basename($path_full);
        $image->thumb = $filename_thumbnail;

        $game->images()->save($image);
        
        return back()->with('success', "Success!! Image uploaded.");
    }else{
        return back()->with('success', 'Ooops.. something went wrong.');
    }
    abort(500, 'Could not upload image :(');
}
```

The error i receive:

```
Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException
Image source not readable
```

I suspect this is because im not in the correct path, because of these lines from above function:

```
    // resize image
    $path_thumb = Intervention::make("./storage/app/public/" . $path_thumb)->resize(300, 200);
    $path_thumb->save();
```

And it is a real hassel working with explicit paths when using git as deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can make image directly like this:

```
$uploadedFile = $request->file('game_image'); 
$image = Image::make($uploadedFile);
```

Resize it:

```
$image = $image->resize(300, 200);
```

and save it like this:

```
$image_data = $image->encode('jpg')->__toString();
$relative_file_path = 'images/test_folder/';
Storage::put($relative_file_path, $image_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the storage() helper?

```
Intervention::make(storage_path('app/public/") . $path_thumb)
```